# find in string an return the word

Tags: vb.net

I want to find in string some letters and returns the (full word) which contains of this letters and the letters may be in the mid of the word (
or at the first or end of the word
some thing like this

```
Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(string, "From\s+([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)\s*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
If (match.Success) Then
  matchedWord = match.Groups(1).Value
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the regex expression

```
\w*find\w*
```

`\w*` stands for any number of word characters. The `*` quantifier is greedy and extends `find` (the letters we want to find) with a prefix and a suffix of word characters (`\w`) up to the boundaries of the word.

We don't need groups. `match.Value` is the whole word containing `find`.

Comment: than u very much... this exactly whit I asked for ... thanks again